# ADSI Edit failed to create object from extended schema with error 'An invalid directory pathname was passed' 80005000

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, adsi, adlds

So I have been trying to get AD LDS to work, I had an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550339/cannot-create-new-computer-in-adsi-edit-on-an-ad-lds-instance) the solution of which is to extend the schema which I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550339/cannot-create-new-computer-in-adsi-edit-on-an-ad-lds-instance#answer-46553871).

So I tried to create a new computer object and I got the error.

> Operation failed.  Error code:  An invalid directory pathname was passed

[image]

So another [SO question has this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654513/error-80005000-when-moving-computer-to-new-ou-with-vbscript) but for a user script.  This is Microsoft's GUI applet.

EDIT: I restarted the service and deleted other experimental AD LDS instances and then restart ADSI Edit and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted the service and deleted other experimental AD LDS instances and then restart ADSI Edit and it worked.  Solved.